# How I can fix this issue with a json gem on ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems

I tried to install a json gem

```
gem install json
```

and it caused a problem.

So I decide to uninstall ruby-on-rails and install again.

So now I want to execute my project in rails. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\Franco\Documents\GitHub\RisePay-Ruby\Risepay>rails s
Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I tried to install Json again and use the bundle install but it didn't work.

```
C:\Users\Franco\Documents\GitHub\RisePay-Ruby\Risepay>bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.3.2
Using i18n 0.6.11

Gem::InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: when you run bundle install what happens?  show us the log

Comment: Did you follow the instructions?

Comment: did you use rubyinstaller to install ruby?

Comment: yes, I use rubyinstaller to install ruby :P